# Translate BATCH to Bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Hello Unix & Linux Community,

I am here to ask how I can translate a Windows Batch File (.bat), into a Linux Bash File (.sh), because I want to allow a program I made, into Linux. But I have no idea how to get it to work in Linux. I understand that some things, like EXEs, are "non-existent" in Linux.

So, the code I want to translate is too long to fit here, so I have posted it elsewhere, and [here is a link to it](https://thecrafters001.ga/r/81eq). If there is any way to do this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: It's a *600 line script* (even if most of it is bloat): what have *you tried*? This isn't a script writing service.

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://ss64.com/bash/ Many batch commands have near-equivalents in bash.

Comment: @jasonwryan They are asking "how I" can translate the file, which implies that they are asking if there is an automated way, IMO.

Comment: @Sparhawk Not really, It would be great if there was one, but I can try to do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no automated way to convert a BAT script into Bash. This leaves you with two options:

**Option 1. Convert the script manually.**

The script that you linked looks simple enough, which means it shouldn't take much time to convert it once you're familiar with the basics of Bash scripting. [This book](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) should be a good starting point in your studies. [Appendix N](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html) of the book contains a nice glossary that could help you replace your old Batch idioms with Bash ones.

**Option 2. Use `wineconsole`.**

`wineconsole` is part of the Wine compatibility layer that allows executing BAT files on Linux systems:

```
$ wineconsole MyCode.bat
```

See the following [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54266/executing-bat-file) for details on how to do that. Although appealing, this may be a dead end if you want run other Linux programs from your script. Furthermore, not all users will have `wine` installed or consider it an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: I understand that there is no automated way, but thank you for the tips! I think ```echo``` is the same in both BATCH and Bash Right?

Comment: @TheCrafters001 In the most basic use case, yes, but its command-line options are different. Type `man echo` in the console for the manual.

Comment: So, Say I want to do something like ```set /p``` I would have to do (using the knowledge from the website linked above) ```export -p```?

Comment: @TheCrafters001 No, **there is no direct mapping** between Batch and Bash. Just as an example, to emulate `set /p` you will likely want to use the `read` built-in. **You do need to read the documentation** (`man bash`, `help export`, `help read`, etc.) and/or tutorials to understand what commands and options you need to use to emulate the Batch behaviour. If you're stuck at some point, you should feel free to start a new question, as long as it focuses on one particular aspect. Asking multiple questions in the same topic, especially in comments, is discouraged.

Comment: @undercat note that `man echo` will give you the manual of `/bin/echo` but when you run `echo` in the vast majority of shells, you run the _builtin` `echo` command instead. In bash, you want `help echo` to see its documentation.